# WebRTC native c++ app as win10 service cannot access video source

Tags: c++, windows-services, webrtc

I have an webRTC (native c++ -> node.js) app which allows screensharing. I've tried to make a windows service from it for easy permissions elevation as well as simple auto-start. I've managed to rewrite it as service but to simplify my example I'll skip that. Let's just say I've used [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) service wrapper to run my app as service.

Whether I run service as local system or my own user, when it gets to the point where I request system for video sources, webRTC return nullptr.

```
        SourceList* sources;
        captureScreen = webrtc::DesktopCapturer::CreateScreenCapturer(options);
        captureScreen->GetSourceList(&sources); //Return nullptr!
```

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   sources._Mypair._Myval2.**_Myfirst** was nullptr. occurred

When capturing camera instead of screen everything works fine according to [this guy and only relevant thread in whole internet I found.](https://discuss.atom.io/t/windows-service-webrtc/43989)

Is there a bug in webRTC/win10? Is there some kind of workaround I can use in order for this to work?

Comment: Please specify the platform you are using for WebRTC?

Comment: @Dave123 Web based

Comment: Does Windows refer to OS or app container view?

Comment: @Dave123 I refer to OS, It's Native c++ app(win 10, video source) -> web client( via node.js server). I think web based was kind of misleading here, sorry for that. I use chromium tho so I guess I could refer to that as web app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making web based WebRTC app then i think everthing should work fine.
I don't thing there is bug in either WebRTC and Windows while screen sharing.

1. Make sure you are using Google Chrome for development. (Just an advice)
2. Your webapp app has permission for capturing windows.
3. If your are using Google Chrome then make sure you are running the chrome with command line flag "--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing" e.g. on Windows "Chrome.exe --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing"

[image]

Screensharing web app using WebRTC - https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/

Checkout WebRTC projects on GitHub - https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment

:)

Comment: I think I could mislead you, thanks for an answer tho. As video source I use Native c++ app due to hardware encoding. It's OS native app -> node.js connection. Also, I have already working app I just cannot transform it into a service due to unknown reason.

Comment: I thought you are asking for web based app. I should have looked at code snippet as it has c++ syntax.

Comment: Yeah, that misunderstanding is cause of my bad explanation. Sorry for that.